# retrieve the total number of messages published to a kafka topic for a specific interval of time (1 minute)

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to use a kafka command that gets the total number of messages that were published to a kafka topic during an interval of time (ideally 1 minute). Does a command like this exists? Preferably in an efficient way to get the count, without having to fetch the content of the messages to then count them for example.

Im thinking kafka-console-consumer.sh could help

Comment: `kafka-console-consumer` will consume topics, but has no concept of time windows. You'd need to filter between your start and stop times, then count manually, as you said you want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

An ideal solution can be if you have Prometheus server on top of your Kafka cluster with `jmx_exporter` so you can get it by a simple promQL query.

If not you can use offsetsManager tool, and filter by the timestamp.

Last solution, you can reset offset of some consumer group using timestamp, look at it’s offset and subtract it from the current topic offset

Comment: I believe JMX only shows bytes ingested, not number of messages/offsets

Comment: It is achievable by doing some tricks with rate on the topic offsets.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. By offsetsManager tool, are you referring to kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell ? If so, since it has a time option, I could use 2 commands both with a difference in time of 1 minute and then subtract their outputs to get the total amount of messages for that minute.